# Can I add html to a jsf h:message with a custom component?

Tags: jsf-2

I would like to add a header and footer image to a h:message in JSF 2.0 so it has nice borders.
It looks like the way to do this is to implement a custom renderer for a component and write out the tags. Id like to do this as a composite component but I cant figure out how to say 'dont draw the header and footer unless youre drawing the message'.

Is there a way to do this with a composite component?

Im using mojarra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`FacesContext#messageList(String clientId)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getMessageList%28%29) to get a `List<FacesMessage>` with all messages for a specific client ID (of which you'd usually be interested in only the first one, you can change the below example if you want). So you could just check in the `rendered` attribtue if the list is not empty. Then you can use `<h:outputText escape="false">` to display the message without implicitly escaping HTML. You could if necessary wrap it all in a composite to keep your code DRY.

```
<h:inputText id="input1" binding="#{input1}" value="#{bean.input1}" />
<ui:param name="input1Messages" value="#{facesContext.messageList(input1.clientId)}" />
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty input1Messages}">
    <h3>Some header</h3>
    <p><h:outputText value="#{input1Messages[0].summary}" escape="false" /></p>
    <p>Some footer</p>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Note that this method was not available in JSF 1.x, that's why you'd need to create a custom component for it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. THis looks like an approach for handling h:messages. Would the same work for <h:message for="id1"/> where I want to conditionally render the message for id1?

Comment: Ah right, sorry I overlooked that bit in the question. I've edited my answer.